# Azure Data Flow (Pass output of one data flow to another in the pipeline)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a requirement where I have to pass the select transformation output from one data flow (data flow) to another directly.

Example:

1. I have a data flow with a SELECT transformation as Final step.
2. I have another data flow that needs to take the above SELECT transformation output as input.
3. Currently, I am storing the output of first data flow into a table and getting the data from the table in second data flow which takes long to execute. I want to avoid storing into the table.

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data flows require your logic to terminate with a Sink when you execute them from a pipeline, so you must persist your output somewhere in Azure. The next pipeline activity can read from that output dataset.